# Compatibility of bibtex and biblatex bibliography files?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, bibtex, biber

In the answer to [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/9352) the advantages and disadvantages of Biber vs. BibTeX (and of `natbib` vs. biblatex) were explained. However, one point was omitted: The question of compatibility of bibliographies between BibTeX and `biblatex`.

After using BibTeX for a while, you get a collection of bibliographies in BibTeX style. Furthermore, many journals give BibTeX entries for citations on their home page. A lot of bibliography management programs either support BibTeX export, or even manage BibTeX files directly. Also, advanced editors like Emacs have special support for BibTeX bibliographies.

In short, there's a massive infrastructure for creating and managing BibTeX bibliographies and a big stock of existing ones. Moreover, as was noted in the other question, you cannot use Biber together with `natbib`, which is used by quite a few journals.

Therefore the following question arises: Is the bibliography format of Biber compatible with the bibliography format by BibTeX? Or if not, it there at least an automatic conversion tool?

Note that both directions are interesting: If Biber cannot use existing BibTeX bibliographies, this means that you have to convert every existing BibTeX bibliography, and do so also for BibTeX entries from journals (unless they also offer Biber, but often it's just BibTeX and EndNote) and bibliographies exported from bibliography management programs. On the other hand, if Biber files cannot be used for BibTeX and no conversion exists, it means that any Biber bibliography is useless for journals using `natbib`, and any programs interpreting directly BibTeX bibliography files cannot be used any more (including editor support).

Also, in case that Biber can read BibTeX files, but not vice versa: Does Biber still have advantages over BibTeX if the files are restricted to BibTeX-compatible ones?

Comment: I think it is a problem that I read through all the answers on this page and still have no idea which parts of my .bib file I need to change to use it with natbib and BibTeX. Because none of the answers seems to address this clearly, perhaps the question needs to be reworded to reflect what the answers actually do address.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To parse BibTeX format files, Biber uses a C library called "btparse" which is, for all intents and purposes, 99.9% compatible with BibTeX. So, You should rarely have problem using Biber as a drop-in replacement for BibTeX. As mentioned by others, the issue is rather the slightly different data model which `biblatex` has compared with the data model in BibTeX.

So, your question really relates to the difference in data models between plain BibTeX and BibLaTeX, regardless of whether you are using Biber as the `biblatex` backend. Be aware that in the future, around BibLaTeX 2.x, BibTeX will no longer be supported as a `biblatex` backend as it has too many limitations. Of course BibTeX format data files will always be supported.

The more important question is, as you mention, what the advantages of Biber might be even if you are not using any of the `biblatex` data model specifics. Here are some advantages of Biber in this respect (you can get an idea by searching for the string "Biber only" in the `biblatex` manual), omitting the features which require data source changes:

- Support of data sources other than `.bib` (currently RIS, Zotero RDF/XML, Endnote XML)
- Support for remote data sources (`.bib` files available via ftp or http)
- Support of other output formats (in 0.9.8 it will support GraphViz .dot output for
  data visualisation and conversion to the planned biblateXML format)
- Full Unicode 6.0 support (including file names and citation keys)
- A sorting mechanism which I think is probably as good or better than any commercial 
  product - full Unicode, multi-field, per-field case and direction, CLDR aware and 
  completely user configurable. BibTeX doesn't come close in this regard.
- Automatic name and name list disambiguation. I think this is quite an impressive feature.
  See section 4.11.4 of the `biblatex` manual for a very good explanation of this with examples.
- Completely customisable crossref inheritance rules. BibTeX has a very basic static rule 
  only.
- Automatic encoding and decoding, including UTF-8 <-> LaTeX macros
- Very flexible configuration file "sourcemap" option which can be used to change the
  `.bib` data as it is read by Biber, without changing the actual data source itself. You
  can use this to do all sorts of things like drop certain fields, add fields, 
  conditionally drop/add fields, change fields using full Perl 5.14 regular expressions
  (see [Biber manual](http://mirrors.linsrv.net/tex-archive/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) section 3.1.2).

This last feature is particularly interesting for you as you can potentially map your pure BibTeX `.bib` files into the `biblatex` model on the fly as Biber reads them but without altering the files. It's also very useful for dropping fields like `abstract` which often cause trouble due to LaTeX reserved characters.

There are also some other features implemented in Biber which are available in BibLaTeX 2.x:

- Customisable labels
- Multiple bibliographies in the same refsection with their own sorting/filtering
- "Related" entries - a general solution to the issue of all these "reprinted as", 
  "translated as" etc. requirements.

I forgot to mention that Biber automatically applies the BibLaTeX field and entrytype mappings (address -> location etc.) mentioned in the documentation. It does this by implementing some driver-level source mappings (see `\DeclareSourcemap` and its variants in the biblatex documentation).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. So if I understand you correctly, I can use standard bibtex .bib file and augment them with a file of transformation rules for biber/biblatex. So I can still use bibtex in cases where is is required, but yet use all biblatex features through transformation rules. Is that right? In that case, I think I'll revise my previous conclusion.

Comment: Yes, that should be largely possible.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but I don't think that mapping really helps. Take the example I already mentioned, the `bookauthor` field. It doesn't exist in bibtex; now if I want to make use of this field in biblatex I have to actually write it in the .bib file. There is no way, to automatically map an author or editor field (which are the only ones traditionally supported by bibtex) into a bookauthor field, biber itself can't decide which editor is actually a bookauthor and which one has to remain an editor in biblatex. Mapping is only possible if a clear equivalent exist.

Comment: You're quite right - the mapping can only help when *adding* information if it is static and predictable from the information already in the data. It can't help you with completely new information. But in that case, you can add the new fields anyway and bibtex will ignore them if it doesn't know about them.

Comment: Thank you. I've now switched the accepted answer to yours because it contains the most relevant information.

Comment: I am confused about what this answer has to do with the question. Isn’t the question about compatibility of .bib files across citation systems? The first paragraph of the answer says that biber should be fine parsing .bib files written to use with BibTeX, which answers half of the question, but the rest of the answer is about features/why to use one or the other. I see nothing here about, for example, what entries in a .bib file designed for biber (biblatex?) will fail to work when, for example, compiling with natbib and bibtex.

Answer (score 36):

As a principle: the more you make use of `biblatex`/Biber's strengths, the harder it gets to go back to a traditional BibTeX workflow.

If you come with your BibTeX database and want to use it with `biblatex`/Biber there are only few areas you have to tweak: chapter 2.3 of the `biblatex` manual lists the following points:

- The entry type @inbook. See §§ 2.1.1 and 2.3.1 for details.
- The fields institution, organization, and publisher as well as the aliases
  address and school. See §§ 2.2.2, 2.2.5, 2.3.4 for details.
- The handling of certain types of titles. See § 2.3.5 for details.
- The field series. See §§ 2.2.2 and 2.3.7 for details.
- The fields year and month. See §§ 2.2.2, 2.3.8, 2.3.9 for details.
- The field edition. See § 2.2.2 for details.
- The field key. See § 2.3.2 for details.

Not all of the changes will probably concern you and not all really result in incompatibilities.

The more you delve into `biblatex` and the more you make use of its unique types, fields and features, the more difficult it gets to go back, of course. The whole question of conversion between between the two actually becomes moot, since it's not really a question of different formats but of `biblatex` simply offering many things BibTeX has no equivalent for.

Just one example which was important for me: Traditional BibTeX doesn't have a `bookauthor` field which is a kind of deal breaker in certain areas of humanities. The fact that `biblatex` has this field was one of the main reasons I originally switched to `biblatex`. Now since BibTeX doesn't know about this field there's no sensible way to have a useful conversion between the two. The same is true for many other fields. So going to `biblatex` is a kind of a one way street after you crossed a certain point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's exactly the type of information I was after. So I now understand that as long as the important journals don't accept biblatex/biber bibliographies, it also doesn't make much sense for me to use them on other files.

Comment: This is the kind of information I was looking for except that there is not sufficient information in the answer to determine which biblatex features will cause moving back to BibTeX to fail.

Comment: @RandyCragun Well, basically any field which is not standard `BibTeX` will not work. Those are woo too many to list …

Comment: It should be possible to compactly list the standard `BibTeX` fields, though, right? (I am actually not confident about whether there are standard `BibTeX` fields or whether `BibTeX` just interprets fields however `natbib` tells it to.) And it is probably possible to list options for mapping the most common non-`BibTeX` fields to `BibTeX` fields. I am definitely not suggesting that you, @Simifilm, need to do the work to make such lists, but I would appreciate thoughts from anyone on whether that is what the question is asking for (I think it is).

Comment: @RandyCragun There is, to my knowledge nothing, beyond any kind of standard then original `BibTeX` as it was released by Oren Patashnik back in the day. The original manual with all types and fields is available on CTAN and should be part of all TeX distributions. Since the original release of `BibTeX` various styles have have extended the specification, and while you could argue that, for example, `natbib` introduced elements which have been picked up by other styles, none of them can really be considered a standard.

Answer (score 12):

As you are asking about Biber vs. BibTeX (that is, *binary drivers* for processing the `.bcf` respectively `.aux` file generated by LaTeX with respect to citations) I assume you are using `biblatex` as bibliography package, as Biber does not support any other bibliography package (old-style BibTeX, `natbib`).

With respect to the bibliography databases: AFAIK Biber is *mostly* compatible to BibTeX. It is, however, more picky wrt having well-formed entries, so chances are high that something "does not work" out of the box. If you do not want to fix all this immediately, using `biblatex` together with `bibtex8 -W` is generally a good workaround. You do not have to switch immediately to Biber just for using `biblatex`.

A more serious problem is that old-style BibTeX and `biblatex` are not to a hundred percent compatible wrt the database entries. Actually, `biblatex` cleans up with many idiosyncrasies of the old-style BibTeX database format:

For instance, in old-style BibTeX there are two fields to indicate an address: `address` for the address of the publisher, which is used in all entry types, but `@inproceedings`. For `@inproceedings` entries one has to give the `location` of the venue instead; the `address` of the publisher must not be given (BibTeX warns about this and ignores it). 
With `biblatex`, both are synonyms for "where it has been published", which is makes more sense, as you never use both within the same entry – theoretically. However, many `@inproceedings` entries one finds on the web (ACM, IEEE, ...) contain *both*, even though this is technically not correct. When you have imported these entries to your personal `.bib` files and use them with `biblatex`, the `address` (of the publisher) sometimes overwrites the `location` of the venue, resulting in wrong information.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Actually up to now I'm using neither biblatex nor biber, but I'm trying to find out whether I should (where I'm not constrained in what I use). Especially important for me is that I can at any time go back to bibtex/natbib where required, and that I don't lose all that infrastructure. As far as I understand, for biblatex vs.standard/natbib the changes are localized to a single document. But not so for bibtex/biber. I'm not yet accepting your answer because you only answered part of my question, and I still hope for answers to the rest, esp. about reverse dir.

Comment: Just a minor point: `bibtex` indeed processes `.aux` files, but `biber` processes `.bcf` files, not `.aux` files.

Comment: @AdamLiter: Thanks for the clarification. (I really love the SE-model, where even a 4-year-old answer still gets better!)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a small add-on. One thing I just noticed is that when using the `alphabetic` style of `biblatex`, the `.bib` file may now be more sensitive to the format in which you write the author names. So if you write

```
author = {M.~Mustermann}
```

then the shorthand for your entry in your document will start with `M M` (using the default settings). However, if you use

```
author = {M. Mustermann}
```

or

```
author = {Mustermann, M.}
```

instead, the shorthand for the corresponding entry will be `Mus`. When using `bibtex` and the `alpha` style, the shorthand starts with `Mus` in all three cases. So `bibtex` recognizes the `~` as a separator of first and last name while `biber` does not.

Comment: That really shouldn't be happening. I just tried to reproduce this behaviour and failed (i.e. my tests all gave labels that used the family name as expected). Could you please provide a full example of when you get this weird behaviour (either here, in a new question, or even in a bug report at [the bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/))?

Comment: @moewe You are right, the problem only shows up if one uses protected spaces between first and last name. `bibtex` understands that but `biber` does not. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is probably due to small differences between `bibtex` and the btparse library which `biber` uses internally. In fact, when using `biblatex` and `biber`, such ties are really a bad idea because names are parsed into objects and reconstructed by styles which should make all the formatting decisions (like such tying). You can always use a `biber` sourcemap to remove them from your .bib dynamically before the names are parsed.

Comment: @PLK I fully agree. But when moving from `bibtex` to `biblatex` and `biber`, one may well have such `.bib` files (I had...) and then wonder why things work differently than before.

Comment: Ah, that is not too bad than. `M.~Mustermann` is not the recommended format anyway and I consider the behaviour of BibTeX to ignore the `~` a courtesy rather than a feature that should be exploited.

Comment: @PLK Is there a list of those (or of the known) small differences between btparse and "original BibTeX"?

Comment: @moewe Yes, such a situation basically arises from the fact that `bibtex` does not offer (at least to my knowledge) such a customizabilty to handle the separators of initials automatically like you have with `biblatex` and `biber`. Thus, people might put such formatting stuff into their `.bib` files. Then, when switching to `biblatex` and `biber`, the manual handling of such formatting is not only not necessary anymore but also leads to strange behavior as noticed in this answer.

Comment: Interestingly BibTeX is smarter that I thought it was, the tie is not needed as both `author = {M. Mustermann}` and `author = {M.~Mustermann}` give `M.~Mustermann` in the .bbl` file. In fact I even think BibTeX mainly ignores the `~` and treats it as ` ` in name parsing as bot `Max Mustermann` and `Max~Mustermann` give `Mas Mustermann` without the tie.

Comment: There is no real list of these idiosyncracies - they just come up from time to time. Also, I have hacked `btparse` to make it a bit more UTF-8 aware and so they have diverged a bit. I am hoping that in the future people will start to use something like the experimental BiblateXML. The bibtex format, in particular name parsing, is really an anachronism these days.

Answer (score 2):

An issue that I found is that comments of the form
`@COMMENT text`
work in .bib files for BibTex but not for Biber.

This is discussed more here:
[code comments in a biblatex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325696/160474)