# Biblatex entries in bibtex-mode (emacs)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, emacs, auctex

Biblatex introduces new entries such as `journaltitle` (see [Compatibility of bibtex and biblatex bibliography files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37095/compatibility-of-bibtex-and-biblatex-bibliography-files)).

Biblatex manual, section 2.3:

> In sum, the following items are different from traditional BibTeX
>   styles:
>
> • The entry type @inbook. See §§ 2.1.1 and 2.3.1 for details.
>
> • The fields institution, organization, and publisher as well as the
>   aliases address and school. See §§ 2.2.2, 2.2.5, 2.3.4 for details.
>
> • The handling of certain types of titles. See § 2.3.5 for details.
>
> •
>   The field series. See §§ 2.2.2 and 2.3.7 for details.
>
> • The fields
>   year and month. See §§ 2.2.2, 2.3.8, 2.3.9 for details.
>
> • The field
>   edition. See § 2.2.2 for details.
>
> • The field key. See § 2.3.2 for
>   details.

**I wondering how to set the bibtex-mode of Emacs to handle correctly these news entries.**

For example, I would like bibtex-mode proposes something like:

```
@Article{,
  author =   {},
  title =    {},
  journaltitle =     {},
  date =     {},
  OPTkey =   {},
  OPTvolume =    {},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  OPTpages =     {},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}
```

instead of:

```
@Article{,
  author =   {},
  title =    {},
  journal =      {},
  year =     {},
  OPTkey =   {},
  OPTvolume =    {},
  OPTnumber =    {},
  OPTpages =     {},
  OPTmonth =     {},
  OPTnote =      {},
  OPTannote =    {}
}
```

when creating a new article entry.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emacs supports biblatex entries since [version 24.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.1).

You can specify the BibTeX dialect either from menu `Entry-types > BibTeX dialect > biblatex`, or by adding these lines at the end of the file:

```
% Local Variables:
% bibtex-dialect: biblatex
% comment-start: "%"
% End:
```

If you want to set `biblatex` as default dialect, add the following to your Eamcs init file:

```lisp
(setq bibtex-dialect 'biblatex)
```

Comment: can the equal signs be on the same vertical line?