# code comments in a biblatex file

Tags: bibtex, biber

I checked the documentation and tried some examples. But it doesn't work. `biber` tells me there are `characters of junk` in my bib-file. ;)

Isn't there a way to add code-like comments into a bib file?

e.g.

```
% This is a comment line
# This is another comment
```

Comment: Biber will not say anything about text following `%`; it will also ignore the characters of junk it complains about. See also [Are comments discouraged in a BibTeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261261/35864)

Comment: If the answer in the other question does not help you, make your question a bit more specific.

Comment: @moewe -- the answer you cite certainly covers the territory. i'd be happy to remove my answer here if you think it doesn't add anything new.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Mhhh, I have now added the Biber view to supplement your answer. Let's wait and see what the OP says, we can still close this question as a duplicate later I suppose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Biber ignores the characters of junk it complains about, so technically you can consider that still a comment. Biber will (contrary to BibTeX), however, ignore everything after a `%` without a warning.

So if you start a line (outside an entry) with `%`, that line is considered a comment by both BibTeX and Biber.

The BibTeX example file [`xampl.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/xampl.bib) (described as "a database file with an example of every standard entry type") starts with

```
% Copyright (C) 1988, 2010 Oren Patashnik.
```

so that seems to be an "officially sanctioned" way to add a comment in `.bib` files.

Comment: I agree that Biber ignores stuff following `%` outside an entry, as it ignores other things. But it still generates a warning complaining about so many characters of junk. It does not, however, complain consistently. I'm not sure what the criteria are for complaining, though. Certainly lines beginning with `%` at the top of the file appear to be ignored completely, but it also ignores some lines later, especially if there is white space before the `%`.

Comment: Or maybe it ignores lines whose first non-white space character is `%` and which meet some further criterion e.g. absence of some other character. I can't work it out.

Comment: @cfr Interesting, I'd have thought that at least lines with first non-whitespace `%` would not trigger a warning; I'll check that later.

Comment: @cfr I did some testing (sorry it took so long) and there everything after a `%` in a line was ignored and spaces did not trigger "junk character" warnings, so lines having a `%` as first non-whitespace character are completely (and without junk warning) ignored. That seems to hold for lines within entries as well for those outside. I would be interested to see a line starting with `%` that still generates a warning.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Now I'm intrigued because I've always assumed that it is these lines Biber complains about in my `.bib` files. If it isn't those, I'm wondering which it is!

Comment: @cfr Interesting indeed, let me know what you find out if you decide to examine your `.bib` file. I didn't do very thorough testing though, so there might be weird situations where `%` still trigger junk warnings. I did test it at the beginning of the file and between two entries as well as within an entry, however, and never got any complaints.

Answer (score 8):

i don't know anything about `biber`, but here's what the `bibtex` manual says
about comments:

p.13, item 7:

> For Scribe compatibility, the database files allow an @COMMENT command; it's not really needed because BibTeX allows in the database files any comment that's not within an entry. If you want to comment out an entry, simply remove the '@' character preceding the entry type.

p.14, item 14:

> LaTeX's comment character '`%`' is not a comment character in the database files.

the conclusion must be that there is no way to have an explicit comment within
a `bibtex` entry, at least not the way that is expected in tex files.

however, if a field name is not recognized by the applicable `.bst` file, that field is ignored.  so using a field name "mycomment" might be worth trying.