# How not to use one line in bib file

Tags: biblatex

I am using bib file. Now I do not want use doi. But % is not working. I do not want to remove the line as I may use it later.

```
@article{Epelbaum:2008ga,
  author =       {Epelbaum, Evgeny and Hammer, Hans-Werner and Meissner,
                        Ulf-G.},
  title =        {Modern Theory of Nuclear Forces},
  journal =      {Rev. Mod. Phys.},
  volume =       81,
  year =         2009,
  pages =        {1773-1825},
  %doi =          {10.1103/RevModPhys.81.1773},
  eprint =       {0811.1338},
  archivePrefix ={arXiv},
  primaryClass = {nucl-th},
  reportNumber = {HISKP-TH-08-18, FZJ-IKP-TH-2008-20},
  SLACcitation = {%%CITATION = ARXIV:0811.1338;%%}
}
```

Comment: Please post a full MWE … (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) There are probably ways to not have the DOI shown, but we need more details.

Comment: Try `_doi` or `HIDEdoi`

Comment: Or give `xdoi` a try.

Comment: This will depend on the bibliography backend you use. BibTeX does not have a way of adding comments inside entries. With Biber (which is the default backend for `biblatex`, the package whose tag you have used) `%` will act as a comment character. In both systems (BibTeX and Biber) unknown fields are ignored, so if you rename the `doi` field to something that isn't known like `definitelynotadoi` or `HIDEdoi` as suggested by user187803 the DOI will also be ignored. ...

Comment: ... Ideally it should be the choice of your bibliography style whether or not to show the DOI. Most `biblatex` have a convenient option to disable/enable the DOI, but with many BibTeX styles there will not be such a simple way. (You'd have to edit the `.bst` file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest and most elegant way to suppress the DOI will depend on the bibliography backend (BibTeX vs Biber), the bibliography package and style you are using.

Generally speaking all bibliography backends simply ignore fields that are unknown to the relevant style. So if we make the reasonable assumption that your style does not have a `notadoi` field, you can rename the `doi` field to `notadoi` and the DOI will not be shown. This method should work in all cases.

If you are using Biber, you can actually use `%` to comment out a line inside a bibliography entry. In BibTeX that is not possible because BibTeX does not recognise `%` as a comment character. BibTeX treats everything outside of an entry as comments though, so you could temporarily move the DOI field to after the closing brace of the entry (though that does not seem very practical to me).

See also [Comments in BibTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21709/35864), [Are comments discouraged in a BibTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261261/35864), [code comments in a biblatex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325696/35864).

Ideally it should be the choice of your bibliography style whether or not to show the DOI. Most `biblatex` styles have a convenient option to disable/enable the DOI ([Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23117/35864)), but with many BibTeX styles there will not be such a simple way (you'd have to edit the `.bst` file).